# Getting two values from a mysql table using a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql table for the charges of a hospital. My program currently only gets the price of the checked procedure. But now, I also want to get the procedure name when it is checked.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[2].'</td>';
                $price=$row['price'];
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="'.$price.'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo '</table>';
```

So basically I need to edit this part of the code:

```
$price=$row['price'];
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="'.$price.'">
```

It only gets the row for price. Can the value attribute have two values? I can't just make another checkbox cause that would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code like this

```
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[2].'</td>';
                $price=$row['price'];
        $procedure_name=$row['$procedure_name'];
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er" value="'.$price.','.$procedure_name.'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo '</table>';
?>
```

Then use explode()

Comment: It says: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
I forgot to mention i have two files. One for the checkbox form and then a php file after submission. So I have to POST the variables used in the first file. And the er[] value has two values, the procedure name and the price.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply put the name in another attribute (like title) and whenever you need to get the name you can use some javascript to retreive it.

```
$price=$row['price'];
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="'.$price.'" title="'.$name.'">
```

Comment: Can't you retrieve it using simple POST method on php?